# MGTwitterEngine check if following a user

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, mgtwitterengine

I am using `MGTwitterEngine` SDK in my `iOS` app. I am trying to check if a user is following another user with this method:

```
- (NSString *)isUser:(NSString *)username1 receivingUpdatesFor:(NSString *)username2
{
    if (!username1 || !username2) {
        return nil;
    }
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:0];
    [params setObject:username1 forKey:@"user_a"];
    [params setObject:username2 forKey:@"user_b"];

    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"friendships/exists.%@", API_FORMAT];

    return [self _sendRequestWithMethod:nil path:path queryParameters:params body:nil 
                            requestType:MGTwitterUpdatesCheckRequest 
                           responseType:MGTwitterMiscellaneous];
}
```

this method is always returning a string that is in this format but not the same:

```
CB4C097E-6740-4536-885E-BAF7D8A981FD
```

basically it would be better to get a bolean value, I don't have a clue about what I'm going to do with this value.

any ideas?

**EDIT
the code that initialized the _engine

```
        _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate: self];
    _engine.consumerKey = kOAuthConsumerKey;
    _engine.consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;
```

Comment: ARe you check the result in the delegate or are you reading the return value?

Comment: i am printing the return value to the log, how can i check the delegate?

Comment: but the return value is coming from the delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an asynchronous request, you have to set your class as delegate of the MGTwitterEngine and get the result in these method, that you must implement in your class:

```
- (void)statusesReceived:(NSArray *)statuses forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier;
- (void)directMessagesReceived:(NSArray *)messages forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier;
- (void)userInfoReceived:(NSArray *)userInfo forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier;
- (void)miscInfoReceived:(NSArray *)miscInfo forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier;
```

As you can read in the MGTwitterEngineDelegate.h:

> ```
> // These delegate methods are called after all results are parsed from the connection. If 
> // the deliveryOption is configured for MGTwitterEngineDeliveryAllResults (the default), a
> // collection of all results is also returned.
> ```

There you can check the result value.

Comment: i set my class as a delegate but the methods dont get called.
not even on the MGTwitterEngine class

Comment: Have you initialized it with consumer key and secret key? Post ome code editing the first post please.

Comment: added, the _engine does not have a property delegate

Comment: the method dont even called on the MGTwitterEngine.m class